# Static code analysis for needs of manual testing

Tags: static-analysis

It is possible to use static code analysis tools to figure out which unit tests to run. But is it possible to use (or are there any tools like this?) code analysis for needs of manual testers?

I mean tool wich shows dependencies **source code change => area in AUT (from user point of view)**.

For example: if we have changes in file `some.package.reports.EmployeeJournal.java` it should notify (by building some report) manual to check the page where we download `employee_list.xml`. Sure this tool is expected to be tought by human first.

Comment: "Sure this tool is expected to be tought by human first."
What do you mean? AI?

Comment: @JoãoFarias, I mean just creating links like e.g. "changed file" --> "web-page to test", "changed file" --> "report to test" etc...

Comment: In many years I've worked as tester both manual and automation, I haven't heard of tester that is using code analysis tool, since the primarily user of these tools are the developers that is intended for component testing and sometimes integration test. May I know the reason why you need to do that though in unit tests?

Comment: If it's got a before and after code image to compare, it is no longer static. Some sort of ui impact analysis plugin for the version control system is what this smells like, as long as all of the dependencies are under version control.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this Martin Fowler/Thoughtworks article on [The Rise of Test Impact Analysis](https://martinfowler.com/articles/rise-test-impact-analysis.html) has some answers. It's about a lot more than unit testing, though. MS VStudio has a feature called "Live unit Testing" that might be similar to your wish.

Answer (score 0):

*"from user point of view"* is hard to know, because if your suite does not cover the application well, parts of the user accessible code will never be checked.

Now, putting this problem aside, there are some strategies to increase efficiency of test execution:

- [Jest runs only tests affected by changes, using coverage reports](https://medium.com/@stipsan/best-kept-jest-secret-testing-only-changed-files-with-coverage-reports-3affc8b4d30f).
- [JUnit MaxCore](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/max/MaxCore.html) "keeps track of runtime and failure history, and reorders tests to maximize the chances that a failing test occurs early in the test run"

Comment: Thanks! But this is all about unit test, not about manual testing.

Comment: You've mentioned "to check the page". My understanding was that you meant to perform optimized checks. If you testing, you can use the same principles as risk heuristics. But results will probably be not as good, because testing is broader than checking - you would need to incorporate others risk heuristics, focused on your domain.